# Coordinate descent in integer programing: when does it work?

Tags: optimization, gradient-descent, convex

Denote $N_i=\{0,1,\dots,\bar{n}_i\}$ and define $N=N_1\times \dots \times N_I$. I want to minimize a function $f:N\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. For the functions $f$ that interest me, it is very easy to minimize $f$ coordinate by coordinate so one natural algorithm is to iterate on a mapping $T$ for which the $i$th element is defined as
$$(Tn)_i=\arg\min_{\tilde{n}_i\in N_i} f\left( \left\{ n_1,\dots,\tilde{n}_i,\dots,n_I\right\}\right)$$
until we have convergence. This is essentially a [coordinate descent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinate_descent) algorithm but in a discrete space.

My question is: under what conditions does this approach yield the true global minimum of $f$? For instance, is $f$ strictly convex along each coordinate a sufficient condition for this procedure to work? Also, if anybody has a reference on the topic that would be highly appreciated.

Comment: "Strictly convex" is not a property that can apply to such functions $f.$  Nor is "gradient," for that matter.

Comment: Right, I guess we can think of convexity of the function on the relaxed set, or convexity along each coordinate. No need for a gradient however. I'm happy to consider any nontrivial condition on $f$ that would make this work.

Comment: But when you think of it that way, you are asking whether a method of optimizing a function over a large set $X\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ (such as a convex closed set with nonempty interior) can produce an optimum over a discrete (tiny) subset of points in $X.$  From this abstract point of view it ought to be obvious there is no hope in general that it will succeed.  (If this isn't perfectly clear, draw a picture in one dimension.) This indeed is why integer and mixed-integer optimization is so much harder than convex optimization.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following. I know that integer programing is hard but there are some results out there. In one dimension the algorithm works trivially - I can optimize over any single dimension very easily. I want to know if it can be extended to many dimensions.

Comment: You cannot optimize over a single dimension easily at all when the domain of the function is the set of natural numbers!  For instance, minimize $\log(1+10^{-12}+\cos x)$ for $x\in\mathbb N.$

Comment: This is a primitive of my problem. In this specific problem, it is easy to optimize over a single dimension. I'm asking this question because I have a problem to solve numerically. Along each dimension I only have a few points to check but I have many dimensions which makes the whole problem complicated.

Comment: Then please edit your question to ask about the problem you have rather than a problem you don't, lest you get answers you find inapplicable or that others find confusing.

Comment: There are many functions $f$ that I'm considering which is why I'm asking the question in this form. I have clarified that for the functions $f$ that interest me it is easy to minimize along a single dimension.